# Is there a way to capture some text in a Django template as a template variable?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here's a non-working example which illustrates what I'm trying to do. I've imagined some tags that don't really exist:

```
{% capture variable=my_url %}
    {% url 'foo' id=x %}/blah?x={my_variable}
{% endcapture %}
{{ my_url | urlencode }}
```

If this were a working example, I would want it to produce a URLendcoded version of whatever text was in the "capture" tag, which in this case is a URL.

PHP Smarty Templates have a capture feature documented here:

https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl

Is there a Django template equivalent of this feature?

Comment: I don’t understand. If this is static text in your template, why don’t you just type it already encoded?

Comment: In the real version it won't be static text. I was simply trying to illustrate the idea of capturing text.

Comment: If it’s a variable then you can just do {{ variable|urlencode }} so I still don’t understand why this is any good.

Comment: What if the text to be urlencoded was the combination of static text, variables and tags. PHP Smarty Templates have a feature which can capture any text and store it in a variable. You can't currently apply a filter to a tag, only a variable.

Comment: @dirkgroten - I've changed the template slightly to give a more realistic usage. It still does not change the basic idea: All I want to do is capture whatever text is rendered inside the capture tag and store that in a variable.

Comment: Django templates don't let you do that, Jinja2 does. There's `{% with ... as my_var %}` but that doesn't let you capture more complex expressions. You might be able to write your own template tag that does what you want.

Comment: Django encourages to put business logic in the views. Templates are just about the layout. One could argue that your example above is business logic. Just pass the encoded url as context variable to your template.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by 3rd party package [django-capture-tag](https://github.com/edoburu/django-capture-tag). You need to install it, then use template code like this:

```
{% load capture_tags %}

{% capture my_url silent %}{% url 'foo' id=x %}/blah?x={{ my_variable }}{% endcapture %}

{{ my_url | urlencode }}
```

For the specific use case of manipulating URLs, also check out [django-spurl](https://github.com/j4mie/django-spurl/), which also supports a capture mode of building a URL without displaying it.